# Are there any changes in units of OpenEBS Jiva volume size in the latest 0.7 release?

Tags: kubernetes, openebs, kubernetes-pvc

I was using OpenEBS 0.6 version where Volume size is mentioned by both in Gi and G. But if I use Gi unit in 0.7 version, it is failing to attach to the Pod. I can see PVC is created.

```
kubectl get pvc 
NAME        STATUS  VOLUME                      CAPACITY    ACCESS MODES    STORAGECLASS    AGE 
minio-pvc   Bound   test-minio-pvc-4166758396   2Gi         RWO             mr-standard     1h
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In 0.7 the unit G should be used not Gi. Using G will resolve the issue.